# Spark Streaming Multiple Streaming Jobs

Tags: java, apache-spark, parallel-processing, stream, streaming

I have an application where multiple users are able to specify Spark workflows which are then send to the driver and executed on the cluster.

The workflows should now be extended to also support streamed data-sources. A possible workflow could involve:

1. Stream tweets with a specific hashtag
2. Transform each tweet
3. Do analysis on a windowed frame and visualization

This is working if only one single stream is started at once but gives the "*Only one StreamingContext may be started in this JVM.*" error.

I tried different known approaches but none of them was working for me ("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts = true", increasing "spark.streaming.concurrentJobs", trying to run each streaming context in a different pool, etc.)

**Can anybody tell me what the current best practice regarding parallel streams  with Spark streaming is?**
Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're starting your spark streaming jobs programatically within an existing application - hence the error with the JVM. Spark is specifically not designed to run in the scope of an different application, even this is feasible in stand alone mode. If you want to start spark streaming jobs programatically on a cluster, you will want to use the Launcher, which looks like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkLauncher

object Launcher extends App {

val spark = new SparkLauncher()
.setSparkHome("...")
.setAppResource("..path to your jar...")
.setMainClass("..your app...")
.setMaster("yarn")
.launch();
spark.waitFor();

}
```

there's a blog post with some examples:

https://blog.knoldus.com/2015/06/26/startdeploy-apache-spark-application-programmatically-using-spark-launcher/

the API docs are here:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/SparkLauncher.html